# FIX Message Can 35=X does not have Symbol or SecID/SecIDSource

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

Hi I need help to understand, if 35=X message should contain Symbol/SecID within the repeating group.
The FIX Specification indicates that under the repeating group both 55 and 48/22 are optional.

I received a message from my client without a symbol tag, please help me undersatnd if that was a bad formed message

20150923-15:06:14.976 : 8=FIXT.1.19=336**35=X**34=19153349=SENDER52=20150923-15:06:14.63756=RECEIVER**268=8**279=0269=1270=99.609375271=289279=0269=1270=99.6171875271=241279=0269=1270=99.625271=154279=0269=1270=99.6328125271=139279=0269=0270=99.6015625271=268279=0269=0270=99.59375271=244279=0269=0270=99.5859375271=171279=0269=0270=99.578125271=21610=198

Comment: Since neither 55 or 48/22 are required (ie optional) the message would be well formed under FIX standard. In any case, your message is hard to decypher without a proper seperator (eg take | as a seperator if possible)

Answer (score 1):

You are advised to treat the default FIX message and field definitions as a set of ***suggested*** definitions.

In practice, no commercial FIX counterparty uses these definitions as-is. Every counterparty I've connected to makes modifications, adding or removing fields from messages or groups, creating new fields, or sometimes adding entirely new messages. No counterparty supports every message and field.

When connecting to a counterparty, **do not assume anything**.  Your counterparty should provide documentation on how they expect their interface to be used, and which messages and fields they will send and which they expect to receive from you.

You need to read their specs and modify your FIXnn.xml DataDictionary file to match what they will be sending you.

If their spec says they will send you Symbol and/or SecurityID in a 35=X message, you need to make sure your DD file matches that.

This page might be helpful to you.  (It's technically for the C# QuickFIX/n, but the DD file is the same for all QF versions.)
http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html

Comment: thank you very much, I was about to get back to them, hence just wanted to confirm from the FIX Experts :), thanks